# A meromorphic function with a pole at the origin so that $\lim_{z\to\infty} f$ exists, must be $P(z)/z^m$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, laurent-series

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic on $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, so that $z=0$ is a pole of order $m$ of $f$, and so that the limit $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)$ exists (finite or infinite). Show that $f$ is in the form
> $$f(z)=\frac{P(z)}{z^m},$$
> for a polynomial $P(z)$, so that $P(0)\ne 0$.

**My attempt**: consider $g(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$. Then $\lim_{z\to 0} g(z)$ exists (finite or infinite). I am trying to show that $g(z)=z^m\psi(z)$ for some meromorphic $\psi$. How to continue?

Comment: assume first the limit at infinity of $f$ is not zero; then $g(z)=z^mf(z), g(0) \ne 0$ is an entire function st $g \to \infty, z \to \infty$ since $m \ge 1$ hence it is a polynomial $P(0) \ne 0$ so done; if the limit is zero then $h(z)=f(z)+1 \to 1, z \to \infty$ and $h$ has a pole of order $m$ at zero, so $h(z)=Q(z)/z^m, f(z)=\frac{Q(z)-z^m}{z^m}$ and $Q(0) \ne 0$ means $P=Q-z^m$ has $P(0) \ne 0$